# On Debian jessie, can I specify which dhcp client is used for a particular interface?

Tags: linux, networking, debian, dhcp

I use the `/etc/network/interfaces` file on Debian to configure my network interfaces with DHCP. The relevant section looks like this:

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp
```

The manpage of interfaces(5) tells me:

> The dhcp Method
>
> ```
> This  method may be used to obtain an address via DHCP
> with any of the tools: dhclient, pump, udhcpc, dhcpcd.
> (They  have been listed in their order of precedence.)
> ```

My question: *is there a way to specify which dhcp client is used for each interface **in the interfaces file**?*

Say I have both `dhclient` and `dhcpcd` installed, and I want to use `dhcpcd` for both interfaces, or I want `dhcpcd` for one interface and `dhclient` for another?

Comment: That's an odd thing to do. Any particular reason?

Comment: We used to have setups with esoteric routers where one dhcp client did not work but the other did. So, on Slackware, which we've used before, we made it so you could specify which dhcp client would be used. Perhaps on Debian, the fact that they are all tried in succession makes the explicit config unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

To start `dhcpcd` manually, run the following command:

```
dhcpcd <interface>
```

you can edit the `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` by adding your interface.

A static profile example:

```
interface ethX
static ip_address=192.168.0.10/24   
static routers=192.168.0.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.0.1 8.8.8.8
```